# Улучшить алгоритм для вычисления выражения

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, оптимизация

Есть массив A - размерностью N. Есть массив B - размерностью N-1;
Массив А отвечает за числа в арифметическом выражении, а B - за действие.

Например A = { 1 , 2 , 3 } , B = { 0 , 2 }. Это является представлением выражения "1-2*3". ( 0 - минус, 1 - плюс, 2 - умножить ). Необходимо написать функцию, которая будет вычислять значение этого выражения. Также нужно учесть приоритет вычислений (из-за умножения). Мой вариант кода:

```
double result(vector<double> &a, vector<int> &b)
{
    double last = a[0];
    double res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
    {
        if (b[i] == 2)
        {
            last *= a[i + 1];
        }
        if (b[i] == 0)
        {
            res+=last;
            last = -a[i + 1];
        }
        if (b[i] == 1)
        {
            res +=  last;
            last = a[i + 1];
        }
    }
    res += last;
    return res;
}
```

При возможности необходимо улучшить его как можно сильней. Я понимаю, что он и так в принципе работает за линейное время и асимптотически его особо не улучшишь. Может есть какие-то рекомендации насчет хранения данных, что выльется в более быстрое решение? Единственное требование: чтоб было разделение между числами и операциями.

Вообще полная задача выглядит немного иначе. Массив A - не меняется во время работы, а в функцию передаются различные варианты массива B. Основное время решения полной задачи занимает эта функция. Возможно, есть какой-то вариант 'запоминания' уже каких-то вычисленных шагов, и при небольшом отличии B и B' вычислить только ту часть, которая отличается.

Comment: тебе нужно `i < b.size() -1` в цикле. так как ты берешь `a[i + 1]`.

Comment: @Senior Pomidor размер массива A - n, массива B - n-1, так что все верно

Comment: Лучше всего ознакомьтесь с общим алгоритмом вычисления выражений, который использует 2 стека -- один для операций, другой для  операндов (и промежуточных результатов). Потом можете оптимизировать его под условия своей задачи. Похоже, вам под операнды и промежуточный результат будет нужен стек максимум из 3-х элементов, а откладывать "на будущее" нужно только одну операцию (сложение и вычитание).

Comment: @Harry, неправда, работает. Вы пробовали тестировать или почему вы так говорите?

Comment: Снимаю свое возражение.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать обратную польскую нотацию, она решит вашу проблему. Об ее реализации вы можете прочитать [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/expressions_parsing)

Comment: @Иван Гладуш: Зачем? Какую "проблему" она "решит"? У автора всего три операции: `-` `+` и `*`. Такие сильно упрощенные выражения прекрасно разбираются существенно более тривиальным алгоритмом. И автор его уже реализовал. С точки зрения общего алгоритма сделать полное вычисление быстрее, чем делает это уже приведенный автором код, не получится. Теперь речь идет только о реализационных оптимизациях, типа избежания повторного перевычисления одинаковых подвыражений.

Comment: @avp: Зачем? Суть задачи в том, что автору нужно именно воспользоваться *упрощенной* формой выражения для ускорения кго вычисления.  Каким образом применение более общего (и тяжелого) алгоритма тут как-то сможет помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Если размерности массивов невелики `(b.size() < 16)`, а массив A - фиксированный, то можно:

1. Создать функцию вычисления дескриптора из флагов умножения **d = ∧<sub>(i)</sub> ( b<sub>i</sub> >> 1) << i)**.
2. Создать двумерный массив **ATAB<sub>d,i</sub>**, в котором для каждого значения дескриптора `d` последовательности множителей массива **a** заменены их произведениями.
3. Для каждого нового массива B вычислять дескриптор `d` и вместо массива A использовать **ATAB<sub>d</sub>**, а операции умножения игнорировать.

Такой подход полностью снимает вопрос о старшинстве операций.